# Is there a way to run two commands side by side in my shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface, terminal, tmux

I have a situation where I want to run two scripts at the same time, side by side in my terminal, and see the output of both as they are running.  Now I can do this manually with `tmux`.  I'll start the terminal with tmux, split the pane vertically, and the start each script in their respective panes.

However I'm trying to see if there's a way I can put all of that logic into a script, so someone with no knowledge of tmux could just run it and see the scripts executing side-by-side.

I've been trying to figure this out but I haven't had much luck so far.  But this is essentially what I'm trying to achieve:

`tmux -pane1 'cmd 1' -pane2 'cmd 2'`

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tmux send-keys -t <pane_id> "<command>" Enter` to send a command to a pane. For example, if we are currently active in a window with 2 panes:

```
tmux send-keys -t 0 "<command_1>" Enter && tmux send-keys -t 1 "<command_2>" Enter
```

You can check out more options of `send-keys` [here](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#send-keys)